# Bootstrap carousel dynamic php

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel has thumbnails on the top of my modal.
My carousel only works the **carousel nav controls**
cuz im using in my *href*="#myCarousel **'.$rows['id'].'**"
in the main slider im using my *id*="myCarousel **'.$rows['id'].'**"
So the slider is working fine,but the problem is when i click on the
thumbnails my slider doesn't change.
I already tried to use **'.$rows['id'].'** after my id="carousel-selector-1"
like this id="carousel-selector-1 '**.$rows['id'].'**" and in my data-slide-number="*Number here* **'.$rows['id'].'**"
and it didnt work.

in my java script i tried to make changes and no succsses.

```
   $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
   });

  // handles the carousel thumbnails
  $('"[id^='.$rows['id'].']").click( function(){
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
 id = parseInt(id);
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 });

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
id = parseInt(id);
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
$('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

my carousel...

```
<div class="container">
 <!-- thumb navigation carousel -->
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs'.$rows['id'].'">

        <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
      <ul class="list-inline">
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
            <li> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
       <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
        </ul>

</div>


<!-- main slider carousel -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

            <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                <div id="myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" data-slide="next">›</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

what is worng?

Comment: got the code from bootsnipp

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: im trying to load images from my database,in my carousel.my imgs from my rows loads fine,but the problem is when i click on my thumbnail,my silder dont slide,it only slides when i click on my carousel nav controls.

Comment: bootstrap version   3.3.7

Comment: why you need to set the click function handler with $('"[id^='.$rows['id'].']").click(...) instead of $('#carousel-selector-'.$rows["id"]).click(...)?

Comment: i dont know i was just testing

Comment: anyway, $rows['id'] I think will return always the same value, as I can't see any cycle... are you sure about it?

Comment: yeah bcuz in each row i have 7 imgs so like this....http://imgur.com/tzrhtNc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this.
I used inside of my

of my thumbs this...

< li class="col-sm-2" **data-target="#myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" data-slide-  to="1"**>

and so on.